# How to cancel already fired non-repeating NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer, invalidation

**What I want**:
1) 4 puzzle images in UIImageViews, which I can move around
2) after solving puzzle I want to show 2 images instead puzzles: first one just after puzzles are solved, second one 2 seconds after the first image...

**What I have:**
1) if you're solving really fast one puzzle after another you may fall into NSTimer interval, which will swap these 2 images too fast, like after 0.1 sec not 2.0

Is there any way to solve NSTimer, to not interfere with already fired one?

**Solution(?):** I was thinking about blocking interaction, so the second image will appear, but it seems like a poor workaround.

Comment: Why would you want to cancel an already fired non-repeating NSTimer? It's done its job already??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep a reference to this timer (as a property or as an iVar).

Then simply call `[myTimer invalidate]; myTimer = nil;` when you want to cancel it.

EDIT:

If you are not keeping reference to your timer (if you're creating it from scratch inside code block) there's always a danger of creating multiple instances...

Comment: isn't that nonrepeating timers are self-invalidating after firing them ?

Comment: It's hard to say more without seeing the code. But your original idea (blocking user interaction) is not a poor workaround - although it might be annoying for users.

Comment: well I returned to invalidating and keeping it in ivar, it's debugging, but I have to test if new/old timers are not interferring with eachother

Comment: It should work. But again - it's hard to say where the exact problem is without seeing the code :)

Answer (score 1):

Write setter method, Like this. Whenever you need to cancel timer

```
self.myTimer = nil;

- (void)setMyTimer:(NSTimer *)inTimer
{
   if (inTimer != mMyTimer)
  {
    [mMyTimer invalidate];
    [mMyTimer release];
    mMyTimer = [inTimer retain];
  }
}
```

Hope this might work for you.